# On a random no. form displays except zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I want to display a form if a random number is other than zero to between 15. Here is a code I tried. I have used iframe but I want any other method. And in booking.html there is simple form. I want it to be without iframe how to do it.

```
function myFunction(){
    var x=document.createElement("IFRAME"); 
    x.setAttribute("src","booking.html"); 
    x.style.height="700px"; 
    x.style.border="none"; 
    x.style.float="center"; 
    document.getElementById("ran").appendChild(x); 
} 
var z=Math.floor(Math.random()*15); 
if(z==0){ 
    document.getElementById("ran").innerHTML=
        "sorry no seats available </br> Please select another date to book ticket"; 
}else{ 
    document.getElementById("ran").innerHTML=
        "HURRY UP "+z+" seats available !!!</br></br>"; 
    window.onload=myFunction; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you tagged your question with jQuery, you could benefit from the `load` method:

Define two areas in your HTML : one for the message, one for the booking page:

```
<div id="ran">
    <div id="msg" style="white-space: pre"></div>
    <div id="load"></div>
</div>
```

The `white-space: pre` is just to facilitate line-breaks in your text, without having to resort to HTML encoding.

In Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    var z = Math.floor(Math.random()*15); 
    if (!z) {
        // Preferably don't use html(), but text(): 
        $("#msg").text("Sorry, no seats available.\nPlease select another date to book ticket");
    } else {
        $("#msg").text("HURRY UP, " + z + " seats available !!!"); 
        // Here comes the magic of jQuery which does all the Ajax stuff:
        $("#load").load('booking.html');
    }
});
```

However, if the booking page belongs to your site, why not just merging the pages into one? You could include it, but hide it with `style="display:none"`.

```
<div id="ran">
    <div id="msg" style="white-space: pre"></div>
    <div id="booking" style="display:none"> <!-- hide initially -->
         <!--- just example code. Put your own stuff here --->
         <form action="book.php" method="POST">
             Date from: <input type="text" id="from"><br>
             Date until: <input type="text" id="until"><br>
             <!-- etcetera .... -->
         </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in Javascript you would show it only when there are seats available:

```
$(function() {
    var z = Math.floor(Math.random()*15); 
    if (!z) {
        // Preferably don't use html(), but text(): 
        $("#msg").text("Sorry, no seats available.\nPlease select another date to book ticket");
    } else {
        $("#msg").text("HURRY UP, " + z + " seats available !!!"); 
        $("#booking").show(); // Only show form when there are seats available.
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for answer but i was using iframes so i enetered booking.html and in bookig.html there is form to fill details and now there is no need to use url how to add form in your code..??

Comment: If you want the form to be inline, then just encode it in the `div id=load` part. See my update.

Comment: but in this if seats availale is zero still user can fill details of the form and i dont want that part.!!

Comment: OK, updated the code. Now the form is hidden when your page loads, and via Javascript it is shown only when *z* is non-zero.